# Accessing data sent by JQuery AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have trouble accessing data sent to the php script by using JQuery's ajax method.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["data_to_send"])) {
        $data_received =  $_POST["data_to_send"];
        echo $data_received;
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    function send_data(){
                       var request = $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: "test.php",
                          data: {data_to_send:"data_object"},
                          success:function(data){
                              alert(data);
                          }
                        });
                    }
                    $('button').click(send_data);
                });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <button>Click to send data</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The ajax call succeeds as success callback is invoked. However $_POST array remains empty after a successful ajax call. I am not sure why $_POST is NULL after I made that ajax call.

Comment: what is alerted by this line `alert(data);` after success?

Comment: How about putting quotes in data object as this : {"data_to_send":"data_object"} ?

Comment: data_object and the html of this page. I expected only the data_object to be alerted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["data_to_send"])) {
    $data_received =  $_POST["data_to_send"];
    echo $data_received;
    exit(); <-- add this line 
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. Now when the success callback is invoked, alert(data) outputs "data_object" which is correct. However, " echo $data_received;" is still not showing anything.

Comment: if you want to show something after ajax success, maybe change alert(data_object)  to  $('body').prepend(data_object)